# How after placing order to change customer order email using Create a Event Observer

Tags: magento2

How after placing an order to change customer order email using Create an Event Observer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `events.xml`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_before">
        <observer name="change_customer_email_before_order_Place" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ChangeEmail" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Create `ChangeEmail.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/ChangeEmail.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $order->setCustomerEmail('abc@gmail.com'); 
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Hope it will work for you!

Let me know if you have query

Comment: Thanks its working for me